# How to exclude directories in glimpse?

Tags: glimpse

I'm using glimpse and I want to exclude searching through some files.  I'm using a shared version of glimpse so I can't place a ".glimpse_exclude" file in that directory.  I tried putting this file in my own local directory but that didn't work (maybe the answer to my question is more about where I can place this file so that glimpse will find it and use my local version?).

I see that there's a "glimpse -W "a;~b" which can exclude an expression (b, in this case), but I want to exclude a directory, something like:

```
glimpse -F "~exclude/this/directory/" mysearchwords
```

The best I have is to pipe this through grep and use grep's exclude functionality:

```
glimpse mysearchwords | grep -v "exclude/this/directory"
```

My main issue with this is that it loses glimpse's color coding so is a bit harder to look through the results.

**In sum**: what's the best way to exclude files for glimpse, without using the .glimpse_exclude file, and/or where can I place that file locally so it will be used when I run searches but will not affect the global glimpse command shared across my network?

Answer (score 1):

In glimpse 3.5, as per http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/glimpse/CHANGES ,

> 3.0 --> 3.5
>   - added "-f filename" option to glimpse: it allows you to restrict the
>     search to only those files whose names appear in "filename".
>   - fixed the agrep bug where -n was not working with ISO characters.